# ClickOnce не работает setup.exe

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-5, clickonce

Сделал приложение на C# WinForms, нужно его опубликовать и сделать обновляемым, для этого использую ClickOnce с такими настройками:
Публикация локально, обновление и установка с ftp сервера (однако нигде не спрашивало имени и пароля пользователя). Подписей никаких не ставил.
В итоге при попытке запустить setup.exe появляется ошибка такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог ошибки:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.19044.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/home-pc/Downloads/Scanner_p2p.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Scanner_p2p.application, Version=1.0.0.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Scanner_p2p.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/home-pc/Downloads/Application Files/Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11/Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.
        + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [06.08.2022 10:04:51] : Activation of C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Scanner_p2p.application has started.
    * [06.08.2022 10:04:51] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [06.08.2022 10:04:51] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [06.08.2022 10:04:51] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/home-pc/Downloads/Application Files/Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11/Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\home-pc\Downloads\Application Files\Scanner_p2p_1_0_0_11\Scanner_p2p.dll.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Версию дотнета надо угадать? Покажите, как воспроизвести эту ошибку у себя.

Comment: Дотнет 5.0, visual studio 2019. Возникает при запуске setup.exe с любого из устройств

Comment: Возможно, неправильно где-то собираю, но не нашел как правильно все собирать и заливать

Comment: текст ошибки текстом приложите

Comment: Добавил лог ошибки